# Spring boot не видит jsp-файлы

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jsp, spring-boot, jetty

Здравствуйте!
Я закончил писать свое веб-приложение с использованием **Spring MVC**, **Spring Seurity** и **Hibernate**, но по тех заданию мне нужно, чтобы оно работало **во встроенном jetty-контейнере**, в то время как разрабатывал его я, запуская во внешнем jetty, встроенном в **IntelliJ IDEA**. В англоязычном разделе данного ресурса, мне посоветовали для этой цели использовать spring boot. Ну я так и сделал, т.е. создал в IDEA новый spring boot проект и перетащил туда все файлы готового проекта, естественно адаптировав spring boot под готовые xml.

Итог таков, что сервер благополучно запускается, но выдает ошибку 404 при доступе на любую страницу приложения:

[image: error]

Также я заметил, что файлы jsp представлений просто не попадают в target директорию после компиляции или упаковки проекта:

[image: folders]

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться!

Мне нужно, чтобы все работало как задумано и чтобы на выходе был 1 исполняемый jar или war файл.

Исходный код проекта можно посмотреть и скачать [здесь](https://github.com/IngeniousTom/DVDExchange-on-spring-boot-).

P.S. Проект желательно запускать в IntelliJ IDEA.

**UPDATE 1**

[image: ран/дебаг]

Comment: Вся ваша конфигурация находится в XML файлах, а ее входная точка в файле web.xml. Но Spring Boot не инициализируется через web.xml, как Spring MVC. Если вам нужен исполняемый файл, то [используйте main class](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-first-application.html#getting-started-first-application-code). И лучше всего настраивайте Spring Boot как полагается - через `application.yml` и аннотации.

Comment: А как мне перевести имеющиеся xml spring конфиги в java конфигурации? distatcher-servlet.xml еще понятно как перевести, но spring-database.xml и spring-security.xml - ума не приложу. По поводу входной точки - я обновил вопрос и приложил скрин окна run/debug configurations и там отчетливо видно, что входная точка проекта - файл spring boot aplication. Должен ли я удалить web-фасет из проекта вместе с web.xml?

Comment: Да, прошу прощения, не заметил ваш main class. Попробуйте добавить [эту зависимость](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp/pom.xml#L33) в проект. В этом же проекте пример настройки Spring Boot + JSP. Все примеры конфигурации через аннотации есть в документцаии Spring Boot или в тех же сэмплах. Например. [Web Security](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-secure)

Comment: @enzo Мой проект согласно ТЗ должен быть на встроенном Jetty, а проект, где вы указали зависимость - на Tomcat. Нужна ли мне эта зависимость если я использую jetty?